# The topology on bounded sets in $X$** of pointwise convergence on $B$ is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

If $B\subset X$* is a *norm*-separable

How can we prove that:

The topology on bounded sets in $X$** of pointwise convergence on $B$ is metrizable.

$X$*$=B(X,\mathbb{R})$ : dual space

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $B = \{ \phi \in X^* : \|\phi\| \leq 1\}$?

Comment: Let $(\varphi_n)\subset B$ be dense subset. Consider metric
$$
d(x,y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{|x(\varphi_n)-y(\varphi_n)|}{1+|x(\varphi_n)-y(\varphi_n)|}
$$

Comment: @Mike $B \neq \{\phi \in X$*$:||\phi||\le 1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See theorem 33 in [this notes](http://perso.crans.org/lecomte/Math/WeakTopologies.pdf) and apply it to $X^*$.